# Spectrum of the background radiation on earth

Tags: thermal-radiation, cosmic-microwave-background, convection

Suppose we consider an object of temperature $T_o$, whereas the air temperature is $T_a$. The object will exchange heat with its environment via a range of processes:

- Radiating and absorbing heat
- Thermal conduction between the object and its support
- Thermal exchange with the surrounding air - which we could loosely term *convection*
- etc.

The object will eventually settle on some stationary temperature, which may however be different from the temperature of the surrounding air - mainly due to the fact, that the radiation absorbed by the object is not black body radiation (at least certainly not black body radiation at the temperature of the surrounding air). The well familiar example is a dark object left outside on a sunny day. On a larger scale, the Earth does not have the temperature of the surrounding space, and even warming.

For actually doing calculation, one would need to know the spectrum of the background radiation under different conditions:

- Outdoors and indoors during a day (here the Sun is the main source of the radiation, even if the day is not sunny)
- Outdoors and indoors at night
- During a polar night
- In caves, ocean floor and other places never subject to direct sunlight

I am loking for the actual data, as well as for discussion of various sources of radiation and their relative importance.